# LTSpice, can I have separate plot panes?

Tags: ltspice

I have LTSpice for mac.
I can add more than one plot pane in the same window.
Can I have plot panes in separate windows? (In order to have diagrams with different dimensions on my desktop)

Comment: On the MSWindows version of LTSpice you can right-click the plot pane, and select "add plot pane"

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, that's not possible. But you can run multiple instances of LTspice and you can load the `.raw` file and select whatever traces you have. The downside is that after each run, the `.raw` file will need reloading for each of the external instances of LTspice.

One thing that could help is to save the plot settings (make the waveform window active, click save). Then, when loading the `.raw` file externally, the waveform window will show the saved traces.

Or you could use the `.step` command to get all the desired traces inside one plot, in the same window.